# How to confine three.js OrbitControls to a specific Angular2 component or Div

Tags: angular, three.js

I have a page that has multiple Angular2 components in individual DIV's. One of the components is a THREE.js scene using OrbitControls.

When I scroll with the mouse wheel or click and drag, the 3D model properly rotates and zooms. However, this happens no matter where my mouse pointer is. I need to be able to use the mouse wheel to scroll down a list in another component.

How can I limit/confine the controls for the THREE.js scene to its particular component or DIV?

Comment: When you create your OrbitControls, try to put renderer's domElement as the second parameter: `var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement)`

Comment: Thank you @prisoner849 . That did it.

Answer (score 0):

To limit the controls to the particular component or Div, do as @prisoner849 mentioned - when you create the OrbitControls, put the renderer's domElement as the second parameter:

```
var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement)
```